# How to Split the pandas column into chunks of n length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am dealing with a large pandas data frame and it contains two columns :

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'text': ['Expression of H-2 antigenic specificities on', 'To study the distribution of myelin-associated'], 
     'id': [1, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I want to check if text length is larger than 2 then split the text into chunks of 2-2 works and if the length is smaller than 2 then don't select take that row.

First I selected the rows which have len >= 2:

```
df['len'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
df        = df[df['len']>2].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now I want to select split the text into chunks of 2 words and make multiple rows, something like this (This is expected output) :

```
                   text  id
0         Expression of   1
1         H-2 antigenic   1
2      specificities on   1
3              To study   2
4      the distribution   2
5  of myelin-associated   2
```

There is `explode` method but I am not getting how to split into chunks while using explode method?

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.split()
df.explode('text')
```

which gives (Not as above expected output):

```
                text  id
0         Expression   1
0                 of   1
0                H-2   1
0          antigenic   1
0      specificities   1
0                 on   1
1                 To   2
1              study   2
1                the   2
1       distribution   2
1                 of   2
1  myelin-associated   2
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @BEN_YO Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us fix your output

```
fixeddf = df.groupby([df['id'], df.groupby('id').cumcount()//2]).agg({'text':' '.join,'id':'first'}).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[270]: 
                   text  id
0         Expression of   1
1         H-2 antigenic   1
2      specificities on   1
3              To study   2
4      the distribution   2
5  of myelin-associated   2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the `explode` like you already are, by breaking the string in chunks of 2 first. Try this -

```
def chunks(s, c):
    return [s[i:i + c] for i in range(0, len(s), c)]

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: chunks(x.split(),2))
df = df.explode('text').reset_index(drop=True)
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(' '.join, 1)

print(df)
```

```
                   text  id
0         Expression of   1
1         H-2 antigenic   1
2      specificities on   1
3              To study   2
4      the distribution   2
5  of myelin-associated   2
```